# What is the URL scheme for search keywords in the LinkedIn iOS App?

Tags: ios, xcode, linkedin-api

I want to open linked in app from my app with preset search text. I have find the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054873/what-is-the-url-scheme-for-searching-keywords-in-the-linkedin-ios-app) but no one have answered to the question. I don't actually know whether it is exist. Please help me on this, Any link or hint would be appreciated.